# IE not loading XML content until I open Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, get

I have a page that loads product information from an XML file using a jQuery AJAX get request. This works  well in FF and Chrome however the content doesn't load in IE. It will however load the data after opening the developer window and refreshing the page! Does anyone know why?

Here is my jQuery AJAX request:

```js
//Load the xml file
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/" + cat + ".xml",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    success: function(data) {
      alert('xml successfully loaded');
      var xml;
      if (typeof data == "string") {
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xml.async = false;
        xml.loadXML(data);
      } else {
        xml = data;
      }
        //Get total number of products in the category
        $(xml).find('dataroot').each(function() {
            var pTemp = $(this).attr('count');
            catName = $(this).attr('catTitle');
            console.log(catName);
            pTotal = Number(pTemp);
        });

         //Fill the correct entries onto the page
         while (count<=pTotal) {
              $(xml).find('product').each(function() {
                  if (count>lCounter && count<hCounter) {
                      var pName = $(this).find('ProductName').text();
                      var pImage = $(this).find('Photo').text();
                      var pCode = $(this).find('ProductCode').text();
                      var pDesc = $(this).find('WebDescription').text();
                      if (cat.substring(0,2)=='cs') {
                          var pPrice = $(this).find('PartyShackPrice').text();
                      } else { var pPrice = $(this).find('RRP').text(); }
                      var pSize = $(this).find('size').text();
                      var pLink = '<a href="item.html?'+cat+'-'+pCode+'">';

                      var pHTML = '<div id="'+pCode+'" class="box">';
                      pHTML += pLink + '<img src="images/SMALL_IMAGE/' + pImage + '" width="70" height"100" /></a>';
                      pHTML += '<div class="boxText">';
                      pHTML += pLink + '<div class="boxTitle">'+pName+'</div></a>';
                      pHTML += '<div class="boxDesc">'+pDesc+'</div>';
                      if (pSize !== 'Not Applicable') { pHTML += '<div class="boxSize">'+pSize+'</div>'; }
                      pHTML += '<div class="boxPrice">£'+pPrice+'</div>';
                      pHTML += pLink + '<div class="boxBuy"></div></a>';
                      pHTML += '</div></div>';

                      $("#products").append(pHTML);
                  }
                  count +=1;
              });
         }

        //Work out the total number of pages the product list is split up into
        if (pTotal%50==0) { pageTotal = pTotal/50; } 
        else { pageTotal = Math.floor(pTotal/50) + 1; }
        console.log('pageTotal - ' + pageTotal);


        //Show path of the current page
        getPath(cat, catName, 0);

        //Depending on page number show previous and next buttons and display product counter
        if (pageTotal==1) { //page 1 and only one page
            $("#prev").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#next").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#counter").append('1 - ' + pTotal + ' of ' + pTotal);
        } else if ((pageNum==1) && (pageTotal!=1)) { //page 1 and multiple pages
            $("#prev").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#next").append('<a href="products.html?'+cat+'-'+(pageNum+1)+'">Next &gt;&gt;</a>');
            $("#counter").append('1 - 50 of ' + pTotal);
        } else if ((pageNum==pageTotal) && (pageTotal!=1)) { //last page when theres more than 1 page 
            $("#next").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#prev").append('<a href="products.html?'+cat+'-'+(pageNum-1)+'">&lt;&lt; Previous</a>');
            $("#counter").append((((pageNum-1)*50)+1) + ' - ' + pTotal + ' of ' + pTotal);
        } else { // a middle page
            $("#next").append('<a href="products.html?'+cat+'-'+(pageNum+1)+'">Next &gt;&gt;</a>');
            $("#prev").append('<a href="products.html?'+cat+'-'+(pageNum-1)+'">&lt;&lt; Previous</a>');
            $("#counter").append((((pageNum-1)*50)+1) + ' - ' + (pageNum * 50) + ' of ' + pTotal);
        }

        //Display page number
        $("#currentPage").append(' ' + pageNum + ' of ' + pageTotal);
    },
    error: function() { alert('failure'); }
});
});
```

Also IE should call either the success alert or the error alert however it does neither until opening the developer window and refreshing the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I knew what the problem was just by reading the title of your question on the SO main page. And reading the code in the question confirms it. The problem you have is the line `console.log(catName);`

IE (and some other browsers) don't initialise the `console` object until the developer window is opened.

Prior to this, trying to use `console` will return `undefined`, and will cause your script to stop running.

The first lesson here is not to leave debugging code in your program after you're done with it. Calls to the `console` should only be there while you're testing the program; when you've finished with them, take them out.

The second lesson is that if you *do* need to have `console` calls in your code, you should wrap them in code that checks if `console` exists before it tries to use it. There are a number of ways to do this, from a simple `if(console) {console.log(...);}` all the way through to writing your own debugging class. How you do it is up to you, but it is generally a good idea to write all `console` code this way, even when you're just doing a bit of debugging, to avoid the kind of issue you're having here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Use if(window.console) {console.log(...);}. if(console) {console.log(...);} will not work because undefined variables cannot be referred to directly.

Answer (score 0):

Let jQuery do what it does best. Replace all of this:

```
dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
success: function(data) {
  alert('xml successfully loaded');
  var xml;
  if (typeof data == "string") {
    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(data);
  } else {
    xml = data;
  }
   ...
```

With this:

```
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
  alert('xml successfully loaded');
  ...
```

Comment: That is what I originally had but I had added in the above code to try and implement support for IE. Unfortunately this still doesn't work. You can see the actual page here [link](http://www.thepartyshack.net/products.html?ac12)

Comment: @user1001898 IE8 throws JS errors because it doesn't recognize `console.log`. Is that what's happening for you?

Comment: I have removed all my console.log and it seems to be working, does it now work for you?

Comment: @mjohnston Yes, but I'm getting a different JS error in IE8 from somewhere else in your code. Still, I'm glad you found the real problem.